# Why are there so many attempts by an anonymous user to access /wp-login.php?

Tags: security

I looked at `/admin/reports/dblog` today. There were five request in two minutes by an anonymous user to view `/wp-login.php`. These requests have been happening for an hour at least and continue 2-3 times per minute.

1. What are the possible explanations for this strange behavior?
2. What can/should I do about it, if anything?

Comment: Sounds like a bot probing your site.

Comment: It's just bots scanning for exploits. You don't need to do anything, except serving a faster 404 response for those pages, as described in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/152732/199.

Comment: Even if these requests have been happening for an hour? Seems odd for a bot to be poking the same thing for such a long time.

Comment: May be bad programming by the bot, may be multiple bots, there are all sorts of reasons. As kiamlaluno said, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Fyi, that's the WordPress login page. They're not targeting your site specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As kiamlaluno said:

> It's just bots scanning for exploits. You don't need to do anything,
>   except serving a faster 404 response for those pages, as described in
>   [drupal.stackexchange.com/a/152732/199.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/152732/199.)

Answer (score 0):

For D8 you could use [Drupal Perimeter Defence](https://www.drupal.org/project/perimeter)

> Basic perimeter defence for a Drupal site. This module bans the IPs
>   who send suspicious requests to the site. The concept is: if you have
>   no business here, go away.
>
> Use the perimeter module if you get a lot of requests to '**wp-admin**' or
>   to **.aspx** urls on a linux server, or other similar requests.
>
> Currently, the module bans users who generate "page not found" events
>   for requesting any of the following url patterns:
>
> ```
>   private $bannedPatterns = [
>     '/.*\.aspx/',
>     '/.*\.asp/',
>     '/.*\.jsp/',
>     '/\/blog_edit\.php/',
>     '/\/blogs\.php/',
>     '/\/wp-admin.*/',
>     '/\/my_blogs/',
>     '/\/system\/.*\.php/',
>     '/.*systopice.*/',
>   ];
> ```
>
> The module is optimized for performance and designed to be activated
>   when a Drupal site is targeted by hackers or bots.